# Disabling select all Ctrl+/ keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 19.10

In Ubuntu, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> keyboard shortcut selects all. However, it interferes with other shortcuts I use and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> already does this. How can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to select all?

Comment: I looked there but couldn't find it.

Comment: Shortcuts are usually defined by the application. Which application uses Ctrl+/ to select all?

Comment: Ctrl+/ seems universal.